# How to give class only clicked element, and remove when other element is clicked using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creatin App using Vue.js,  i have encountered a problem i know how to solve this problem using jQuery, but i can't figure out how i can solve this problem in vue app, I will try to explain my problem briefly, i got list of items, i want to give specific color to only  clicked element, and remove if second element will be clicked, i want to use `e.target` to achieve my goal, any solution? thanks in advance

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    giveColor(event) {
        event.target.className += " green";
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <li class="some" @click="giveColor" v-for="y in 10">
     menu  clicked {{y}}
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742076/vue-js-add-class-to-clicked-button/57742107#57742107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    giveColorTo(y) {
        this.selected = y;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <li class="some" @click="giveColorTo(y)" :class="{green:selected == y}" v-for="y in 10" :key="y">
     menu  clicked {{y}}
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: You've to mark the question as duplicate