# v-if toggles for all items instead of the only clicked item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am listing from loop my items in html, I am trying to add an accordion effect to display info about the items, whenever I am toggling this, it changes all items to active instead of the one I clicked on.

I am facing the same issue, whenever I have a lot of input boxes and I want to edit one of them, it triggers the edit option for all the inputs instead of the only one.

```
 div(v-for="review of list" :key="review.id")
    .flex
      p {{ review.name }} 
      box-icon.ml-auto(type="solid" name="down-arrow-circle" @click="toggle()" v-if="!toggled")
      box-icon.ml-auto(type="solid" name="up-arrow-circle" @click="toggle()" v-if="toggled")
    .info(v-if="toggled")
      p test
```

```js
 const toggled = ref(false)
        function toggle() {
          toggled.value = !toggled.value
        }
        
        return { list, toggle, toggled }
    },
```

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742076/vue-js-add-class-to-clicked-button/57742107#57742107

Comment: Are all of your list items sharing the same `toggled` variable?

Comment: @0x5453 Yes, that's the problem, I don't know how can I make it unique for each element

Answer (score 0):

Use an `array` or `object` for `toggled` data.  If using an `object`, the key should be the item id, and use `Vue.set` to set it initially to maintain reactivity.

If using an array, use the item id to indicate a set value.

```
div(v-for="review of list" :key="review.id")
    .flex
      p {{ review.name }} 
      box-icon.ml-auto(type="solid" name="down-arrow-circle" @click="toggle(review)" v-if="!toggled.includes(review.id)")
      box-icon.ml-auto(type="solid" name="up-arrow-circle" @click="toggle(review)" v-if="toggled.included(review.id)")
    .info(v-if="toggled.includes.review.id)")
      p test
```

```js
const toggled = ref([])

        function toggle(review) {
          const idx = toggled.value.findIndex(r=>r === review.id)
          if (idx === -1) toggled.value.push(review.id)
          else toggled.value.splice(idx, 1)
        }
        
        return { list, toggle, toggled }
    },
```